# flutter: sqflite insert return type

Tags: sql, sqlite, flutter, sqflite

As with every database operation in sqflite , insert operation also will be an
asynchronous function, and it will return a Future of type int, as the
insert method will return the ID of the record that was inserted, but in my case it dos not return id of record it return something like this `(Instance of 'Future<int>')`. I want to print the actual numeric value id of my record.

This is my code for inserting data:

```
Future<int> insert_into_Account(Account account) async {


    int id = await db.insert(
      'account',
      account.toMapAccount(),
      conflictAlgorithm: ConflictAlgorithm.replace,
    );
    return id;
  }

  // print data
Future testDb() async {
    db = await openDb();


    var id = insert_into_Account(Account(
      name: 'maliha',
      adress: 'eeee',
      balance: 123,
      issueDate: '333',
      telphone: 'ddd',
      type: 'eee',
    ));
    List lists = await db.rawQuery('select * from account');

    print(lists[0].toString());
    print(id.toString());
  }
```

and result is:

```
I/flutter (11306): {accountNumber: 5, name: maliha, telphone: ddd, address: eeee, issueDate: 333, balance: 123, image: null, type: eee}
I/flutter (11306): Instance of 'Future<int>'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`insert_into_Account` return `Future<int>`. To get id, add `await` in front:

```
 var id = await insert_into_Account(Account(
      name: 'maliha',
      adress: 'eeee',
      balance: 123,
      issueDate: '333',
      telphone: 'ddd',
      type: 'eee',
    ));
```